# Model Primary Key not being Inserted into Query using WhereHas

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model, eloquent

## A Little Background...

My `User` model has the following two relations:

```
/**
 * Get the connections added by the user.
 *
 * @param boolean $accepted
 * @return BelongsToMany
 */
public function addedConnections($accepted = true)
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User\User', 'user_connections', 'user_id', 'connection_id')
        ->wherePivot('connection_type', '=', 'user')
        ->wherePivot('accepted', '=', $accepted)
        ->withTimestamps();
}

/**
 * Get the connections the user was invited to.
 *
 * @param boolean $accepted
 * @return BelongsToMany
 */
public function invitedConnections($accepted = true)
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User\User', 'user_connections', 'connection_id', 'user_id')
        ->wherePivot('connection_type', '=', 'user')
        ->wherePivot('accepted', '=', $accepted)
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

I have attempted to write a method that merges the above two methods to return `connections`. However, instead of returning this as a Laravel `Collection`, I want to return it as a query `Builder` so I can add to the query...

This is what I have implemented:

```
/**
 * Get the connections the user was invited to.
 *
 * @return Builder
 */
public function connections()
{
    return $this
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query
                ->whereHas('addedConnections')
                ->orWhereHas('invitedConnections');
        })
        ->whereDoesntHave('blocked');
}
```

## The Issue...

The problem with this function is that it is not building the query correctly (from what I can see). Instead of returning the connections for the current user, it is returning all connections. This is because of the following two lines in the query:

```
WHERE  user_connections.user_id = users.id
WHERE  user_connections.connection_id = users.id
```

`users.id` should be the id of the current user, not a reference to the `users` table.

## My Question(s)

1. Why is this happening? Why is the model `id` (1, 2, 3 etc) not being inserted into the query instead of the reference to the table?
2. Regardless of what is causing the issue, I am keen to know if there are any better methods of achieving the above?

## Update 1

I think I may have fixed this with the following:

```
/**
 * Get the connections the user was invited to.
 *
 * @return Builder
 */
public function connections()
{
    return $this
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query
                ->whereHas('addedConnections', function ($query) {
                    $query->where('id', '=', $this->id);
                })
                ->orWhereHas('invitedConnections', function ($query) {
                    $query->where('id', '=', $this->id);
                });
        })
        ->whereDoesntHave('blocked');
}
```

Is this the right solution?

## Additional Information

If needed, this is the full SQL query:

```
SELECT
   * 
FROM
   `users` 
WHERE
   (
      EXISTS 
      (
         SELECT
            * 
         FROM
            `users` AS `laravel_reserved_3` 
            INNER JOIN
               `user_connections` 
               ON `laravel_reserved_3`.`id` = `user_connections`.`connection_id` 
         WHERE
            `user_connections`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` -- THIS IS THE ISSUE
            AND `user_connections`.`connection_type` = 'user' 
            AND `user_connections`.`accepted` = TRUE 
            AND `laravel_reserved_3`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
      )
      OR EXISTS 
      (
         SELECT
            * 
         FROM
            `users` AS `laravel_reserved_4` 
            INNER JOIN
               `user_connections` 
               ON `laravel_reserved_4`.`id` = `user_connections`.`user_id` 
         WHERE
            `user_connections`.`connection_id` = `users`.`id`  -- THIS IS THE ISSUE
            AND `user_connections`.`connection_type` = 'user' 
            AND `user_connections`.`accepted` = TRUE 
            AND `laravel_reserved_4`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
      )
   )
   AND NOT EXISTS 
   (
      SELECT
         * 
      FROM
         `users` AS `laravel_reserved_5` 
         INNER JOIN
            `user_blocks` 
            ON `laravel_reserved_5`.`id` = `user_blocks`.`blocked_id` 
      WHERE
         `user_blocks`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
         AND `laravel_reserved_5`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
   )
   AND `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
```